# Изменение CSS для любых сайтов в мобильном браузере

Tags: css

Есть такое расширение для Chrome - Stylebot, которое позволяет задать произвольные правила CSS для любых веб-страниц и сохранить эти пресеты.

Есть ли что-то подобное для мобильных браузеров? Особенно интересует Яндекс браузер. Нужно скрыть на чужом сайте раздражающий div, но именно со смартфона.

Может есть хотя бы подобие инструментов разработчика десктопных браузеров?

Comment: Есть приложение Adguard

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что это вопрос про поиск продукта.

Comment: Про Adguard в курсе, но вот что-то он не совсем так работает, как я предполагал.